# Is it me or i can't sum these?

Tags: javascript, sum

Good morning / Afternoon / evening :).

i have two integers that i want to turn them floats, with 4 decimal numbers to use them on GPS coordinates:

```
var z = y.toFixed(4);
var p = x.toFixed(4);
```

But there are a situation that is bugging me, that is the sum between these 'z' and 'p':

```
var t = z + p;
```

After this instruction, i want to print the result on the screen with some common functions like:

```
document.write(z);  document.write("<br />");
document.write(t);
document.write("<br />");   
document.write("<br />");
```

The result that i get is:

```
0.0000
0.0000300.0000

1.0000
1.0000300.0000

2.0000
2.0000300.0000
```

But what i really want is:

```
300.0000
301.0000
302.0000
```

How can i sum 'z' and 'p', after all? :S

Noob question, i know :S.

Kind regards, 
Sam

Comment: tried to int /float/double z and p and sum them then?

Comment: toFixed converts a number into a string. so at the end you're adding two strings !

Comment: Thank you both for the fast response.

I already checked that situation of the strings, and it's so true :).

Already fixed the bug :). 
T

Comment: Thank you both for the fast responses.

That string situation is the problem of this bug. 

Already fixed my problem. 

Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `.toFixed()` returns a `String` object rather than a `Number`, so the `+` operator performs concatenation.

Instead you should perform the addition of the actual numbers first and *then* perform `.toFixed()` to "round" the result for display.

```
var t = (x + y).toFixed(4);
document.write(t);
```

Comment: This worked fine for me.

Thank you very much for the fast response Jack! :)

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is :

```
var t = x + y;
var p = t.toFixed(4);
document.write(p);
```

Comment: This was, like Jack's solution, the best way to fix the bug.

I apprecitate the fast response pktangyue! :)

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var t = (x + y).toFixed(4);
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/cFSa6/)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response bipen! :).

The solution is already taken and the bug is fixed! :).

Kind regards! :)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript method `toFixed` converts your number into a string. Thus, when you perform operation `z + p` it actually is string concantenation and not addition of numbers. You may first add your numbers and afterwards apply `toFixed`.

Comment: This is an important description to fix the bug!

Thanks once again for the fast response! :)

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

`toFixed()` returns a string, which means you are concating string when you use `var t = z + p`. You need to first sum your coordinates and then call `toFixed()`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response w4rumy! :)

My problem is solved! :)

Kind regards!

Answer (score -2):

How much is `p`? Are you concatenating strings?

Try with `var t = parseFloat(z) + parseFloat(p);`

Comment: I think this should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: -2? Are you joking? I was the first to find the problem and provide a working solution

Comment: I didn't dv you, but doing `parseFloat(x.toFixed(4))` is redundant, because it's the same as `x` (more or less).

Comment: Well, if `x.toFixed(4)` returns a String, then I don't think this is redundant, right?

Comment: Vault, i was working with GPS coordinates, and their format are double/float.

But i want to sum more values to each coordinate with some other values.

I appreciate your given solution , but i already fixed the bug. Check the previous responses so that you can learn too :).

Thank you once again for your fast response! :)

Kind Regards!